# arpspoofing and ARP table

Tags: arp

I dont understand the ARP table of 1 machine on my testing network consisting of 3 PCs on Ubuntu20

- a client of IP 192.168.0.1
- an attacker of IP 192.168.0.2
- a server of IP 192.168.0.3

On machine n°2 (attacker), I've installed :

- dnsiff and launched arpspoof ( `sudo arpspoof -t 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.3`)
- mitmproxy in transparent mode, which makes a proxy and redirects all the traffic arriving on port 80 to port 8080 by setting properly the iptables rules.

  `sudo apt install dnsiff`

  `sudo apt install mitmproxy`

I activated the ip_forwarding by uncommenting `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in file /etc/sysctl.conf and then reloaded the system :

`sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`

`mitmproxy --mode-transparent -p 8080`

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`

All works but when I open the arp table of machine 1 (192.168.0.1) , I read :

192.168.0.3  @MAC of the attacker  (which is what I expected)

192.168.0.2 @MAC of the attacker (which is surprinsing)

How is it that address 192.168.0.2 appears whereas there is no trace on any wireshark frame , when wireshark listens to machine 1 interface.

Another surprinsing thing occurs when I set manually the @IP et @MAC of the server :

sudo arp -s 192.168.0.3 @MAC of the attacker

This time the ARP table of machine 1 does not display 192.168.0.2 (attacker).

Thank you for any explanation.